# Get the new URL after getting redirected to a new page

Tags: python

When I load this website `https://yewtu.be/latest_version?id=E51gsi_r3HY&itag=137` it reads the URL and redirects me to a new URL which is a video feed. Is there any way I can get the new URL with python without using something like selenium? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure this is what you are asking for:

```py
import requests

before_redirect_url = ...

request = requests.get(before_redirect_url)
after_redirect_url = request.url
```

Comment: no this just gives you back the ```before_redirect_url```

Comment: It might be because the url is blocking requests as it sees it as a bot. It seems your link cannot be opened by this, if you try printing `request.text`. Somewhere should say something along the lines of `429 too many requests`. If the website is set up properly, it should stop rate limiting you, however if it isn't then there isn't much you can do unfortunately.

Comment: I do get error 429. What confuses me is that 429 errors appear due to repeated requests to the server but I just made 1 request.